# How to find ngrams by a grouped column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, nltk, n-gram

I've been able to figure out ngrams from a single list before, but now I want to group it by a column in a dataframe.

When I try to take my original snippet, for the list, and apply it to this dataframe I keep on getting a typeerror for "expected string or bytes-like object". I tried googling, and I wasn't able to find a solution for this.

My dataframe is just set up as two columns, with about 50,000 rows.

```
ID  term
1   the cat jumped over
1   dog jumped over
1   dog jumped through
2   little black hat
2   little black shirt
2   the black shirt 
3   is it snowing right now
3   is it raining right now
3   is it snowing tomorrow
3   is it raining today
```

My ideal result from this dataframe would be showing the ngrams (between two and four) and the frequency of them. So it should be something like this.

For 2-grams:

```
ID Term
1  jumped over (2), dog jumped (2)
2 little black (2), black shirt (2)
3 is it (4)
```

Is this possible? Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from nltk import ngrams, word_tokenize
from functools import partial
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv', engine='python')
df.dropna()
for i in range (2,4):
    _ngrams = partial(ngrams, n=i)
    df['{}-grams'.format(i)] = df.groupby("id")["term"].apply(lambda x: Counter(_ngrams(word_tokenize(x))))
```

Comment: Could you share the expected output?

Comment: edited with the ideal output, based off how the script ran when i used it on a list

Comment: why even use `pandas` for this? better off just iterating over the CSV

Comment: I used pandas because my intent was to groupby the ID column, can I get around that without using pandas?

Comment: use a dictionary where the top most key is the ID? it would look something like `{1: {'jumped over': 2, etc...}}` since you're using `apply` on the dataframe anyways you're not getting any real speed benefit here, and also the code becomes more unreadable, just my opinion

Comment: trying that out now. I am very basic in my Python, so I was just using what I already knew and trying to apply it here, so I get your unreadable comment and I'm trying to get better there :)

Comment: I am still unable to figure it out. Is there any other way to accomplish this? Or if it has to be in a dictionary, is there any way to provide an example of a snippet that could help achieve this?